# Is it possible to transfer data stream via HTTP or FTP protocol instead of TCP/IP

Tags: c#, sockets

The requirement is to transfer bytes data stream(in bytes format) through HTTP or FTP protocol. I am doing it with IP protocol but as it is unable to be handled by load balancers. Right now I am sending data stream by converting into byte format and at receiver's end decoding it into string form. The same thing I wanna do with HTTP protocol.

```
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
              SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
```

Here in `ProtocolType.IP` there should be HTTP but HTTP option is not there.

This is a WinForms application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTTP isn't a protocol at that level - it's an *application* level protocol.

You don't get "an HTTP socket" - you typically get a TCP/IP socket and write HTTP data over that.

See the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) for more details about the network layers involved.

I don't know for sure whether the built-in HTTP client libraries in .NET support streaming requests... you'd probably want to turn buffering off and write to the request stream. See what that looks like at the socket level using something like [WireShark](http://wireshark.org).

Comment: This is very basic thing I didn't consider. Thanks Jon. Can u suggest any way to do load balancing. I have a simulator that is streaming data. and before receiver, I want a load balancer. I came to know that load balancer automatically work for standard protocols like HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, SMTP but not for TCP/IP.

Comment: @Akki: Rather than streaming, are you able to split your data into multiple requests? That would make it easier to load balance.

Answer (score 4):

The `ProtocolType` enumeration does not include HTTP. HTTP is part of the application layer in the OSI model. There has never been a concept of a "HTTP Socket". HTTP is encapsulated within TCP/IP. The `ProtocolType` enumeration refers to the *transport* protocol.

From [MSDN on the ProtocolType enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.protocoltype.aspx),

```
    IP  Internet Protocol.
    IPv6HopByHopOptions     IPv6 Hop by Hop Options header.
    Icmp    Internet Control Message Protocol.
    Igmp    Internet Group Management Protocol.
    Ggp     Gateway To Gateway Protocol.
    IPv4    Internet Protocol version 4.
    Tcp     Transmission Control Protocol.
    Pup     PARC Universal Packet Protocol.
    Udp     User Datagram Protocol.
    Idp     Internet Datagram Protocol.
    IPv6    Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6).
    IPv6RoutingHeader   IPv6 Routing header.
    IPv6FragmentHeader  IPv6 Fragment header.
    IPSecEncapsulatingSecurityPayload   IPv6 Encapsulating Security Payload header.
    IPSecAuthenticationHeader   IPv6 Authentication header. For details, see RFC 2292 section 2.2.1, available at http://www.ietf.org.
    IcmpV6  Internet Control Message Protocol for IPv6.
    IPv6NoNextHeader    IPv6 No next header.
    IPv6DestinationOptions  IPv6 Destination Options header.
    ND  Net Disk Protocol (unofficial).
    Raw     Raw IP packet protocol.
    Unspecified     Unspecified protocol.
    Ipx     Internet Packet Exchange Protocol.
    Spx     Sequenced Packet Exchange protocol.
    SpxII   Sequenced Packet Exchange version 2 protocol.
    Unknown     Unknown protocol.
```

Answer (score 2):

Look http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/7be22396-0f2a-4138-b47a-09d93894185b
The first post shows how to send some bytes through a HTTP-Request.
Adapted for your use:

```
byte[] data;
// ...
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(server);
request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
request.Method = "POST"; // I think, your data is too big for GET
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
try {
    Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    postStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    postStream.Close();
} catch(Exception ex) {
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Why are people downvoting here?

Comment: I don't know, imho it's exactly what the thread-starter wanted.

Comment: why I want to downvote myself? Isn't it a genuin question? I am new to the IT field. I don't think I asked anything wrong.

Comment: @Akki J: I was refering to my answer, not to the downvoting. Imho my answer is what you wanted, but I dont wanted to say: "The thread-starter wanted downvotes"